# msgbus for collection selection in outliner

Tags: python, scripting, collections, outliner, select

I want a callback for Collection selections in the Outliner.
So far I already found a common solution for object selections:

```
handle = object()
subscribe_to = bpy.types.LayerObjects, 'active'

def notify_test():
    print('Notify')

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(),
    notify=notify_test,
)

bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
```

But what bpy.types do I subscribe to when I want a callback for collection selections?
**When I select a different collection in the outliner.**
There is:

```
bpy.types.LayerCollections
```

But there are no 'active' or 'selected' properties for this certain type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `msgbus` is quite limited, I don't think there is a solution using that, but you can use the [`depsgraph_update_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) application handler instead:

```
import bpy

def on_depsgraph_update_post(scene, depsgraph):
    selected_items = None
    area  = next(area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'OUTLINER')
    
    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        window=bpy.context.window,
        area=area,
        region=next(region for region in area.regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'),
        screen=bpy.context.window.screen
    ):
        selected_items = bpy.context.selected_ids

    for item in reversed(selected_items):
        if isinstance(item, bpy.types.Collection):
            print("You have selected a collection:", item.name)
            return

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(on_depsgraph_update_post)
```

Comment: Thats what Im using currently, I should have mentioned that. The downside is that it also fires events Im not interested in.
I guess theres no cleaner way. 
I.e.: When you are using a UI Panel you can just push your function into 'poll' call.
Thank you Harry!

Comment: @rbx775 yes I agree. there's lots of different events that fire it, which is kind of uncool, i hope they will change it to make events and callbacks more modular